access shell alias with dmenu
I have a collection of bash commands (one liners) that I use on a regular basis to open new shells or start programs with a given set of arguments. As I use dmenu, I'd like to be able to use those commands from my shell and from dmenu. So defining an alias in my .bashrc isn't enough, I have to put these commands in a dedicated file. The file needs then to be executable and stored in a $PATH known to dmenu. If I do so, the alias becomes useless because the shell will find the executable. But that means I have to create one file per command. It's annoying.
Is there a way to store all those commands in one file (or at least in a more convenient way) so that they can be accessed via shell and dmenu? Maybe something like an alias file read by dmenu...

If you have all your aliases in a single file (let's say ~/.aliases.sh), you could do something like this:
#!/bin/bash

. ~/.aliases.sh

alias |
  awk -F '[ =]' '{print $2}' |
  dmenu |
  xargs -ICMD bash -O expand_aliases -c $'. aliases.sh\nCMD'


I like your answer but this doesn't merge the executable with the alias. It only works for alias..For me, It's a step in the right direction, but not the full story. I'll work on this when I'll have time.

If I were in your situation I would simply adopt the "collection of small script files" option, since that makes everything available regardless of what shell you're using (or even if you're not using a shell and something is just calling exec()).

You will have to write a script to pipe them into dmenu and execute the result.
this is a example script
#!/bin/bash
cachedir=${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-"$HOME/.cache"}
if [ -d "$cachedir" ]; then
    cache=$cachedir/dmenu_run
else
    cache=$HOME/.dmenu_cache # if no xdg dir, fall back to dotfile in ~
fi

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
  aliases=( ~/.bash_aliases )
fi

if [ ~/.bash_functions ]; then
  functions=( ~/.bash_functions )
fi

source $aliases

cmd=`(
    IFS=:
 if stest -dqr -n "$cache" $PATH || stest -fqr -n "$cache" "$aliases" || stest -fqr -n "$cache" "$functions"; then
          (
            stest -flx $PATH
            alias | awk -F '[ =]' '{print $2}'
            compgen -A function
          ) | sort -u | tee "$cache" | dmenu "$@"
    else
        dmenu "$@" < "$cache"
    fi
)`

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$(grep '^alias' $aliases|cut -d'=' -f1|grep $cmd)" ] || [ -z $(which $cmd) ]; then
        echo -e "source ~/.bash_aliases \n $cmd" | bash -O expand_aliases &
    else
        exec $cmd &
    fi
fi

source
